# Fibre of GIT morphism

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, geometric-invariant-theory

Let $ V $ be an affine variety (over $ \mathbb C$) with an action of a reductive group $ G$.  I would like to consider the morphism $$ \pi : V \rightarrow V // G = Spec \, \mathbb C[V]^G $$
Let $ v \in V $.  Assume that the orbit $ Gv $ is closed in $ V $. Assume also that the stabilizer of $ v $ in $ G $ is finite.

**Question:**
<strike>Is the following true?</strike>  What additional hypothesis should I place on $ v $ in order to ensure that the following is true?

---

The scheme-theoretic fibre $ \pi^{-1}(\pi(v)) $ equals $ G v $.

---

I looked in Mumford's book, but I could not find this.

**Example:**
Here is an example where this does work.  Suppose that $ G = SL_k $ and $ V = Hom(\mathbb C^k, \mathbb C^n) $ and let $ v $ be an injective map.  Then $ V // G $ is the variety of pure $k$-tensors (the cone on the Grassmannian).

Comment: That already fails for the scaling action of $\mu_n$ on $\mathbb{A}^2,$ $n>1.$  If you want a connected group, consider the action of $\mathbb{G}_m$ on $\mathbb{A}^2\times\mathbb{G}_m$ by $s\bullet((x,y),t)=(sx,sy,s^{-n}t).$

Comment: You seem to be asking about smoothness of $\pi$ at the points of the orbit.  The only smoothness result that I know for group quotients is the Chevalley-Shephard-Todd Theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chevalley%E2%80%93Shephard%E2%80%93Todd_theorem

Comment: Thanks for the example.  If I calculate correctly, taking $\mathbb G_m $ acting on $ \mathbb A^2 \times \mathbb G_m $ and $ n = 2 $, I find that $ \pi^{-1}(\pi(1,0,1)) = \{(a,b,c) : a^2 c = 1, b^2 = 0 \} $, which is not reduced (because of the $ b= 0 $), but is set-theoretically the orbit.  I have modified my question, to emphasize the second part.

Comment: Is the fibre always set-theoretically equal to the orbit?  (Unfortunately Chevalley-Shepherd-Todd doesn't seem to help me since my groups are not finite.)

Comment: Formally locally, your quotient is a quotient of a "slice" by the stabilizer group of a point (a more precise result is the Luna Etale Slice Theorem).  Thus, your question about the scheme-theoretic fiber (your original question that I was answering) does reduce to a question about quotients by finite groups.

Comment: I think the answer to the set-theoretic question you asked can be answered affirmatively using results here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1110.4236.pdf .

Comment: Sean: I just took a look at that paper, but I couldn't see which result there was useful.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but you are assuming your point is properly stable I believe (using the language in that paper) and so Theorem 3.8 says that properly stable is equivalent to there not being a limit to a 1-parameter subgroup.  The fiber you are asking about is set-theoretically a union of orbits with a unique closed orbit.  Two such orbits are in the same fiber if and only if their closures intersect which occurs if and only if there is a limit to a 1-parameter subgroup.  So the fibre cannot have any other orbits since properly stable implies no limits.

Comment: I am still confused, since even if $ v $ is properly stable, there may exist some other $ x \in V $ (which is not stable) with the property that the closure of its $G$-orbit contains $ v$.  I don't see how Theorem 3.8 helps us, since it just tells us about 1-parameter subgroups acting on $ v $.

Comment: @JoelKamnitzer The "properly stable locus" is a Zariski open subset.  Sean Lawton is correct.

Comment: I see, thanks very much!  That settles the question about set-theoretic fibre.  Still the question about scheme-theoretic fibre remains ... is there any additional hypothesis which would imply that the scheme-theoretic fibre is the orbit.

Comment: @JoelKamnitzer I think that if the action is scheme-theoretically free you can make this conclusion since then the quotient is principal bundle.  But given the nature of Jason's examples, I would guess no such other general criterion exists (aside from the statement I believe that is implied by Jason's remarks about the Luna Slice Theorem, namely, that it should be true if orbit has its stabilizer group generated by pseudoreflections).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am just recording what was said in the comments so this question does not appear *completely* unanswered.

Let $\pi_X:X\to X//G$ be the GIT quotient of an affine variety over $\mathbb{C}$ by a reductive group $G$.  WLOG assume the action is effective.

First, a point is properly stable if its orbit is closed and it has finite stabilizer.  The locus of properly stable points is Zariski open.  Then since each fibre $\pi_X^{-1}(\pi_X(x))$ is a union of orbits, this union contains a unique closed orbit, two such orbits are in the same fibre if and only if their closures intersect, and such intersections can be detected by 1-parameter subgroups, we can conclude that if $x$ is properly stable then $\pi_X^{-1}(\pi_X(x))$ is set-theoretically the orbit $Gx$.

Please see *[Stability of Affine G-varieties and Irreducibility in Reductive Groups](https://arxiv.org/abs/1110.4236)* by Casimiro and Florentino as a reference.

As pointed out by Jason Starr in the comments, the fibre is not generally scheme-theoretically the orbit however. A counter-example is the action of $\mathbb{G}_m$ on $\mathbb{A}^2\times \mathbb{G}_m$ by $s\cdot((x,y),t)=(sx,sy,s^{-n}t)$ for $n>1.$  As noted by the OP, this is apparent even for $n=2$.

We now refer to the Luna Slice Theorem; see [Luna’s slice theorem and applications](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00742479/document) by Drézet.  Let $V$ be a slice at a properly stable point $x$, and let $\pi_V:V\to V//S$ be the corresponding quotient where $S$ is the stabilizer of $x$ (necessarily a reductive subgroup).  Then there is an isomorphism: $$G\times_S \pi^{-1}_V(\pi_V(x))\cong \pi_X^{-1}(\pi_X(x)).$$

So, the fibre is the scheme-theoretic orbit if it is smooth which, by the [Chevalley-Shephard-Todd Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chevalley%E2%80%93Shephard%E2%80%93Todd_theorem), occurs if and only if the stabilizer is generated by pseudoreflections.

Comment: Great summary! Thanks.